# Absolute image URL in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

How can I get the absolute URL of an image in Rails.

Rails serves the images using assets.

So an image by the name "logo.png" is actually stored as "logo-776bfb0d3b4bdea029da753cf63916e2.png".

This is not a problem when I need to access the image using a Rails server as I render it using the <%= image_tag %> helper.

But I need to pass the actual URL to an API which will then render the image.

So how can I just get the physical URL??

Answer (score 0):

This is the name of the file. It will be in your public/assets directory and the url will be 
your-site-name/assets/logo-776bfb0d3b4bdea029da753cf63916e2.png.

Note this will change when you precompile your assets and the file is given a new fingerprint. You will be much better off using the rails image_url helper to give you the URL and passing that to your API.

Comment: Have already tried it. I get a "NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `image_url'" error

Comment: @Zeutheus: you are probably trying to use the helper in a context where it is not defined. try using ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url

Comment: @Zeutheus from your comment to PoloniculMoc you need format.json { render: json => { url => ActionController::Base.helpers.image_url('logo.png')} } or include the helpers as suggested by PoloniculMoc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 4. Then the image will be in name_of_your_app/app/assets/images/.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to include [ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html). Or you could just call `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("image.png")`

Comment: Using the built in respond_to helper to return a json response for APIs

Comment: @Zeutheus so is it like `format.json { render :json => @object}`?

Comment: yes.. how does it matter.. my question is how can i get the actual url with the hash encoding...

Comment: Yes, it matters, because image_tag isn't available where you're trying to call it. use `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag(image_name)` or include the module in whatever class you need it. Or better yet, build your responses with [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder).